# Crisp throws an error 'BoundWidget' object has no attribute 'field' when i want to submit

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to do an advanced rendering on my Django crispy forms
the form section of my index.html looks like this

```
            <form method = "post"> 
              {% csrf_token %}
             {{ form.organization |crispy}}

  
           <div class="form-row">

           <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
           {{ form.start_date |crispy}}
           </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
           {{ form.end_date |crispy}}
           </div>

           </div>
           {{ form.recommend |crispy}}

           </form>
```

Comment: Provide your form which causing this error

Comment: what do you mean by the form

Comment: you're using django form provide that with corresponding view function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.